# Syntax to declare a hyperlink field value (both Url and Description)

Tags: 2010, hyperlink, elements-xml

In my list instance I'm attempting to pre-populate a data row with this hyper link: [Project Link](http://google.com/) However I can't locate documentation and none of these guesses at syntax work:

```
<ListInstance ...>
 <Data>
   <Rows>
     <Row>
       <Field Name="URL">http://google.com;"Project Link"</Field>
     </Row>
     <Row>
       <Field Name="URL">http://google.com;Project Link</Field>
     </Row>
     <Row>
       <Field Name="URL">http://google.com;#Project Link</Field>
     </Row>
   </Rows>
 </Data>
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frustratingly simple - there **must be a space between** the delimiting comma the first character of the title.  If no space the comma and title are concatenated with the link.

```
<ListInstance ...>
 <Data>
   <Rows>
     <Row>
       <Field Name="URL">http://google.com, Project Link</Field>
     </Row>
   </Rows>
 </Data>
```